# preg_replace removing spaces too

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am using this code to use a "tagging" system, like twitter has: @username and it will link up to their profile

```
preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", '<a href="http://www.buddyweb.me/profile/?username=$1">@$1</a>', ereg_replace("[[:alpha:]]+://[^<>[:space:]]+[[:alnum:]/]","<a href=\"http://assets.buddyweb.me/scripts/run_link.php?url=\\0\" target=\"_blank\" class = \"user_created_link\" title = \"External Link\">\\0</a>", $original));
```

It works find but if there are two next to each other, e.g:

`@someone @else`

it will link them up to the profile, but it removes the space between them, e.g:

`@someone@else`

I know it's something easy but I'm kinda new to PHP so I wouldn't really know what to remove, I've tried removing the `/`'s from the above code but that ruins the whole thing

EDIT

I have published the full code.

Comment: Not removing the spaces for me...

Comment: I don't think the problem is in the regex, probably there's something with the output part.

Comment: I have published the full code.

Comment: Did you try adding a space @Frank

Answer (score 0):

i would think you can add a space after the anchor tag:

```
preg_replace("/@(\w+)/", '<a href="http://www.buddyweb.me/profile/?username=$1">@$1</a> ',$string)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's strange that it does link all @usernames cause you didn't specify the **g** modifier at the end of the regular expression. The g modifier will replace all occurences. Lbu's answer should actually be adding 1 extra space so you *should* end up with 2 spaces.

```
preg_replace("/@(\w+)/g", '<a href="http://www.buddyweb.me/profile/?username=$1">@$1</a>',$string)
```

A great website to practise with is http://gskinner.com/RegExr/ Good luck!:)

Comment: @Rez, PCRE does not understand the `g` modifier.  You may need to turn your `error_reporting` value up.  PHP should be emitting a Warning for you when you use this code.